# Issue with strpos, strlen, and substr

Tags: php

So I am trying to dissect my column names using the following function

```
function disectColumnName($columnName){
    echo "fieldname: " .$columnName. "<br>";
    $periodLengths = array("min","hr","dy","wk");   # Array of periodLength Options
    $periodLength = $periodLengths[array_search($columnName, $periodLengths)];  # Find which periodLength is used in columnName and sa
    $periodDuration = substr($columnName, 0, strpos($columnName,$periodLength));
    echo 'periodLength: '.$periodLength . "<br>";
    echo 'periodDuration: '.$periodDuration . "<br>";
    $movingAverages = array("e","s");
    $movingAverageLoc = $movingAverages[array_search($columnName, $movingAverages)];
    echo "movingAverageLoc: " .$movingAverageLoc . "<br>";
    $startOfString = strpos($columnName,$periodLength)+strlen($periodLength);
    $stringLength = strpos($columnName,$movingAverageLoc)-(strpos($columnName,$periodLength)+strlen($periodLength));
    # strpos($columnName,$movingAverageLoc) returns blank, should return strpos when movingAverages = "S"
    echo "StartOf: ". $startOfString . "<br>";
    echo "StrLen: ". $stringLength . "<br>";
    $movingAverage = substr($columnName,$startOfString,$stringLength);
    echo 'movingAverage: '.$movingAverage;
}
```

`disectColumnName` is in a loop which process through the following array of column titles -

```
 array(12) { [0]=> string(7) "14min3e" [1]=> string(7) "14min4e" [2]=> string(8) "14min41e" [3]=> string(7) "14min3s" [4]=> string(8) "14min41s" [5]=> string(8) "14min32s" [6]=> string(9) "14min321s" [7]=> string(9) "15min321s" [8]=> string(8) "15min41s" [9]=> string(9) "15min321e" [10]=> string(8) "15min41e" [11]=> string(8) "15min32e" }
```

The problem is that the column titles ending in `'s'` are not generating the correct `StringLength` or `movingAverageLoc` (it's showing `e` instead of `S`).  However if the column name ends in `'e'`, it works perfectly, what gives?

Here is what is currently being output:

```
fieldname: 14min3e
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 14
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: 1
movingAverage: 3

fieldname: 14min4e
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 14
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: 1
movingAverage: 4

fieldname: 14min41e
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 14
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: 2
movingAverage: 41

fieldname: 14min3s
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 14
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: -5
movingAverage: 

fieldname: 14min41s
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 14
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: -5
movingAverage: 

fieldname: 14min32s
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 14
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: -5
movingAverage: 

fieldname: 14min321s
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 14
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: -5
movingAverage: 

fieldname: 15min321s
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 15
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: -5
movingAverage: 

fieldname: 15min41s
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 15
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: -5
movingAverage: 

fieldname: 15min321e
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 15
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: 3
movingAverage: 321

fieldname: 15min41e
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 15
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: 2
movingAverage: 41

fieldname: 15min32e
periodLength: min
periodDuration: 15
movingAverageLoc: e
StartOf: 5
StrLen: 2
movingAverage: 32
```

Comment: This might be a whole lot easier if you looked at PHP's sscanf() function - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php - which would allow you to dissect your sting in one line of code

Comment: I assume `array_search($columnName, $movingAverages)` always returns false (casts to 0 etc.), as the the `$columnName` is _never_ 'e' or 's', but always something prepended before it, so it will _never_ be found in `$movingAverages`.

Comment: Hah, I was almost ready to suggest regexes... But Mark Bakers suggestion is _spot on_ :)

Comment: None of your `array_search()` calls work. This function looks for exact matches of the whole string, not partial matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list($periodDuration, $periodLength, $movingAverage, $movingAverageLoc) =
    sscanf($columnName, '%d%[a-z]%d%[a-z]');
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much! I just read up on sscanf.  What a fantastic function, I had never hear of it before. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
$movingAverageLoc = $movingAverages[array_search($columnName, $movingAverages)];
```

This part:

```
array_search($columnName, $movingAverages)
```

is searching the array, array("e","s") for the column name, "15min41e" for example. Unless your column name is "e" or "s", it's always going to return false. So for all your example data it's essentially doing this:

```
$movingAverageLoc = $movingAverages[false];
```

which is the same as:

```
$movingAverageLoc = $movingAverages[0];
```

That's why you're always getting "e" for $movingAverageLoc. You'll need to fix that line at least.

However, There are much easier (less confusing) ways of doing what you want to do. Using [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) for one:

```
$string = "1wk2dy5hr15min431e";
$res = preg_split('~([0-9]+)([a-z]+)~i', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($res);
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => wk
    [2] => 2
    [3] => dy
    [4] => 5
    [5] => hr
    [6] => 15
    [7] => min
    [8] => 431
    [9] => e
)
```